# ANDROID- how to save selected item from gridView in a string?

Tags: android, android-intent, gridview

I am showing captured images in one layout using different gridView for each category (Shirts , Trousers e.t.c). The number of the gridViews is 6.

I am trying to select one image from each gridView and via onClick method in the button to show them in another activity but the code i wrote doesn't work.

I suppose something is wrong with the strings.

Can anyone help me to fix this? Thnak you in advance!

```
public class CreateOutfit extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

private DatabaseHandler handler;

GridView grid1;
GridView grid2;


ArrayList<Clothes> clothes = new ArrayList<Clothes>();
GridviewAdapter GridAdapter;

String image1;
String image2;


public static final String ITEM_IMAGE1 = "image1";

public static final String ITEM_IMAGE2 = "image2";



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.clothes_grids);

    handler = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

    grid1 = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid1);
    grid1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            image1 = String.valueOf(view.findViewById(R.id.cloth_image_grid).getContext().toString());


        }
    });

    fillGrid1();

    grid2 = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid2);
    grid2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            image2 = String.valueOf(view.findViewById(R.id.cloth_image_grid));

        }
    });

    fillGrid2();


    ImageButton btn_in = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_insert);
    btn_in.setOnClickListener(this);


}


public void fillGrid1() {

    clothes = (ArrayList<Clothes>) handler.readGridShirts();

    GridAdapter = new GridviewAdapter(this, R.layout.grid_row, clothes);

    grid1.setAdapter(GridAdapter);

    for (Clothes c : clothes) {
        String record = "ID=" + c.getID() + " | Category=" + c.getCategory() + " | " + c.getSize();
        Log.d("Record", record);
    }
}

public void fillGrid2() {

    clothes = (ArrayList<Clothes>) handler.readGridTrousers();

    GridAdapter = new GridviewAdapter(this, R.layout.grid_row, clothes);

    grid2.setAdapter(GridAdapter);

    for (Clothes c : clothes) {
        String record = "ID=" + c.getID() + " | Category=" + c.getCategory() + " | " + c.getSize();
        Log.d("Record", record);
    }
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewOutfit.class);

    in.putExtra(ITEM_IMAGE1 , image1);

    in.putExtra(ITEM_IMAGE2, image1);

    startActivity(in);



}
```

}

```
public class ViewOutfit extends Activity {

DatabaseHandler handler;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_outfit);

    Intent i = getIntent();

    handler = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

    ImageView im1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.im1);
    String image1 = i.getStringExtra("image1");
    im1.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(i.getStringExtra(image1)));

    ImageView im2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.im2);
    String image2 = i.getStringExtra("image2");
    im2.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(i.getStringExtra(image2)));


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is: the `string`'s values which are not getting the image path.
According to this line:

```
image1 = String.valueOf(view.findViewById(R.id.cloth_image_grid).getContext().toString());
```

It'll never return the image's path... Did you try to display this value in Logcat? It should display the memory's address of the widget's `ImageView`, and not the image's path.

---

You should override `Object getItem(int position)` in `GridView`'s adapter, get the item's model (known as `Clothes`) and retrieve its image's path. Thus, the adapter should has this:

```
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return clothes.get(position); // return the item by its position
}
```

Then, in the class, when you set the listener, it should be as this:

```
grid1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // retrieve the model's item
        Clothes selectedItem = (Clothes) tShirtGridAdapter.getitem(position);
        // then, get the image's path and save it
        image1 = selectedItem.image_url; // "image_url" is the String path's value in model
    }
});
```

---

Beside, you saw `adapterTShirt` in the above code, because you used the same variable of the adapter `GridAdapter` and you set a new instance of the adapter on this line for both `GridView`s:

```
GridAdapter = new GridviewAdapter(this, R.layout.grid_row, clothes);
```

This might be better to not re-initialize the adapter and display the same for two gridviews. You'd have two variables (two instances) of the adapter as:

```
GridviewAdapter tShirtsGridAdapter, troussersGridAdapter;

// then
tShirtsGridAdapter = new GridviewAdapter(this, R.layout.grid_row, clothes);
// and 
troussersGridAdapter = new GridviewAdapter(this, R.layout.grid_row, clothes);
```

With this, you will have two separate instances and you can't retrieve the image 's path in click listener from the right clicked item like my snippnet code above.

Comment: WOW!!! You are sooooo helpful! Thank you so much!!  After i read all that you mentioned i think i have little mistakes and if i fix them everything will work fine!! I will try them first thing in the morning and i will let you know! Thanks again i appreciate!

Comment: Good news, @Ntina.Tsif! I'm glad that it works. What about the related answer, did you try with the new structure? :)

Comment: I did everything from above...I didn't even have an Object in the adapter.Then i changed the names of the different adapters as you mention and finally i changed the string as above...and it worked! Now i have to save these choosen images in the existing database and show them in a list maybe. Can i bother you if i will have a problem?

Comment: I asked for [this related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34694633/android-2-different-intents-opens-the-same-activity), if you've succeeded with it now ;). Yes, you can, even without asking me personally (there are a lot of devs in SO which can help you).  Anyway, there is no problem to bother me. Happy coding.

Comment: Oh that! Sorry..! i managed to make it work with only one intent. I just passed in the intent with extras the "image1" with value the string image1 and the same about image2. Everything ok then!!

Comment: No problem, Ntina. Therefore, could you accept my previous answer (in order to inform others devs that your question has been resolved)? Thanks in advance. I'm really glad to ear that it's working now :)