# ANDROID - 2 different intents opens the same activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm making an app and at this point i have two different intents carrying images. I' am trying to pass those images in the same activity in imageViews.

Can anyone help? Thanks!!

My code is:

```
ImageButton btn_insert = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_insert);
    btn_insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i  = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewClothes.class);
            i.putExtra(ITEM_IMAGE1, image1);
            startActivity(i);

            Intent i2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext() , ViewClothes.class);
            i2.putExtra(ITEM_IMAGE2 , image2);
            startActivity(i2);


        }
    });
```

And in the second activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.view_clothes);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    ImageView image1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.im1);
    image1.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(i.getStringExtra("image1")));

    Intent i2 = getIntent();
    ImageView image2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.im2);
    image2.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(i2.getStringExtra("image2")));



}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dubbled the `Intent` and you launched the next `Activity` twice.

A single Intent can have multiple objects and pass those to an Activity. One Intent is used to launch the next Activity but you can easily add several objects with it as follows:

```
// first activity
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewClothes.class);
i.putExtra(ITEM_IMAGE1, image1);
i.putExtra(ITEM_IMAGE2 , image2);
startActivity(i);
```

And received all images like:

```
// next activity
ImageView image1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.im1);
ImageView image2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.im2);

Intent i = getIntent();
image1.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(i.getStringExtra(ITEM_IMAGE1)));
image2.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(i.getStringExtra(ITEM_IMAGE2)));
```

---

Another solution might be to use a `StringArray` for your several images. In the first Activity, you could populate the array:

```
// populate the array
String[] images = new String[] { image1, image2 };
// pass the array
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewClothes.class);
i.putExtra(ARRAY_IMAGES, images);
```

And pass into the Intent to retrieve it like this:

```
// retrieve it
String[] images_passed = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra(ARRAY_IMAGES);
// show the images
image1.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(images_passed[0]));
image2.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(images_passed[1]));
```

Comment: THANK YOU for your immediate response! I 'll try it! Thank you again!

Comment: Glad to help @Ntina.Tsif. After you'll try, let me know if my answer helped.

Comment: actually i think this will not work...because i forget to mention that i have multiple gridViews.. and image1 is a photo from the first one and image2 is from second one...sorry! Any thoughts?

Comment: i have more code in this question....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34521149/android-how-to-save-selected-item-from-gridview-in-a-string

Comment: I answered too @Ntina.Tsif. I think the main problem is the strings `image1` and `image2`. With `getItem()` in the adapter, by passing the image's path from the model, you could pass it into the intent. Hope this helps.